# Program to view Shared Memory in Windows?

Tags: windows, shared, shared-memory

I'm looking for a program to view and browse the (local) shared memory in Windows x32/x64.

I know this exists because I've seen it in action before. For some reason Google and MSDN fail me on this one.

Comment: What do you call "shared memory"?  There's no such term in the Windows API.

Comment: I assume this means memory-mapped files which are commonly called shared memory (even inside msdn).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think [Accesschk](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb664922.aspx) can do this.

From the commandline: `accesschk.exe -osv > objects.txt`

Search for: "Type: Section"